# Access SQL convert table field text into number

Tags: sql, ms-access

In an Access Database with multiple tables, one [table = "IT9001"] gets monthly updated via new import, so the format resets monthly, too. One column hat the format **text** but I need it in **long integer**.

current SQL: `alter table [IT9001] alter column [numbers] LONG;`

After this the field type is **long integer**, but the numbers are still shown as text (on the left side), because the field format has an "@" in it, like any other field with text, too. If I remove the "@" they are shown as numbers (orientation on the right side). How do I change the field format and delete the "@"?

And I am not going to use the import assistant (or what ever it's called) to change the format manually. The data gets imported in the same type as it is in the excel file.

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: `ALTER TABLE IT9001 ALTER COLUMN numbers SET FORMAT 0;` shall do your task.
Please let me know if it works

Comment: sadly I get an error syntax message and the word FORMAT gets highlited

Comment: to be able to connect different columns from different tables, they need to have the same field type. after using my current SQL above, I am able to connect this table "IT9001" with another one via the column **numbers**. They are shown as text but are treated like numbers. so technically the problem is solved... but it looks strange... but still, thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, 
`ALTER TABLE IT9001 ALTER COLUMN numbers SET FORMAT 0;` has removed `@` from the column ? Can you cross-verify it whether `@` is removed from the column values ?

Comment: not it hasn't, I can't run the code because of the syntax error... but they are treated like numbers after running my code ``ALTER TABLE IT9001 ALTER COLUMN numbers LONG;`` but the ``@`` is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manage a field's `Format` property with Access SQL.

Use VBA to remove it from the field's `Properties`:

```vb
CurrentDb.TableDefs("IT9001").Fields("numbers").Properties.Delete "Format"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to avoid VBA because the users don‘t know it. But that would solve it…